# Count elements with jQuery and CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 8 buttons and I want to calculate the total of them for each button with the class `active`.

I tried the code below but is not working well. Can anyone help me to solve it this problem?

```js
// Show Price
function showPrice() {
  price = 0;
  btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1");
  btn2 = document.querySelector("#btn20");
  btn3 = document.querySelector("#btn6");
  btn4 = document.querySelector("#btn-book-20");
  btn5 = document.querySelector("#btn-book-6");
  btn6 = document.querySelector("#btn-book-12");
  btn7 = document.querySelector("#btn-book-13");

  if (btn1.getAttribute("class") == "active") {
    ele = document.querySelector("span #price").firstChild.textContent;
    price = price + Number(ele);
  } else if (btn2.getAttribute("class") == "active") {
    ele = document.querySelector("span #price2").firstChild.textContent;
    price = price + Number(ele);
  } else if (btn3.getAttribute("class") == "active") {
    ele = document.querySelector("span #price3").firstChild.textContent;
    price = price + Number(ele);
  } else if (btn4.getAttribute("class") == "active") {
    ele = document.querySelector("span #price4").firstChild.textContent;
    price = price + Number(ele);
  } else if (btn5.getAttribute("class") == "active") {
    ele = document.querySelector("span #price5").firstChild.textContent;
    price = price + Number(ele);
  } else if (btn6.getAttribute("class") == "active") {
    ele = document.querySelector("span #price6").firstChild.textContent;
    price = price + Number(ele);
  } else if (btn7.getAttribute("class") == "active") {
    ele = document.querySelector("span #price7").firstChild.textContent;
    price = price + Number(ele);
  }

  $("#amountInDollars").html(price);
}
```

````html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="active" type="button" id="btn1">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 1</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span id="price">10</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>
<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn20">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 2</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span id="price2">20</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>
<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn6">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 3</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span id="price3">19</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>
<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn-book-6">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 4</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span id="price4">13</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>

<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn-book-20">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 5</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span id="price5">14</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>


<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn-book-12">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 6</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span id="price6">16</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>

<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn-book-13">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 7</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span id="price7">12</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>


<span id="amountInDollars"></span> ```
````

Comment: Maybe help us help you by giving us the HTML code...

Comment: Can you share the HTML markup

Comment: If you want to calculate total of all items that has the class active then you should use only if for all the conditions. Here you are using if() else if(). So if the condition if matches then it wont execute the else if other conditions

Comment: anybody help me!

Answer (score 1):

As your code shows you are using jQuery (`$("#amountInDollars").html(...)`), I'll give an example using jQuery as it seems to be loaded anyway.
I've added a click handler to the buttons so when they are clicked the classes `active` and `desactivate` will be toggled, so you may select which element is active just by clicking it. You may remove this handler if you don't need it, it's just to make the example more dynamic. Active buttons have yellow background.

*Edited regarding the notes bellow i.e. check for no button selected and a missing price.*

```js
function showPrice() {

  var a = $('button.active').map((i,x) => $(x).find('span[id^=price]').first().text()).toArray();
  var total = 0;
  if (a.length) total = a.reduce((p, n) => Number(p) + Number(n));
  $("#amountInDollars").html(total);

}

// DOM ready for your actions 
$(function() {

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').toggleClass('desactivate');
    showPrice();
  });

  showPrice();

});
```

```css
.active{background-color:yellow}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="active" type="button" id="btn1">
  <div>
    <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
      <p>Items 1</p>
      <br>
      <p id="users-number"></p>
      <span id="price">10</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn20">
  <div>
    <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
      <p>Items 2</p>
      <br>
      <p id="users-number"></p>
      <span id="price2">20</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn6">
  <div>
    <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
      <p>Items 3</p>
      <br>
      <p id="users-number"></p>
      <span id="price3">19</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn-book-6">
  <div>
    <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
      <p>Items 4</p>
      <br>
      <p id="users-number"></p>
      <span id="price4">13</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn-book-20">
  <div>
    <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
      <p>Items 5</p>
      <br>
      <p id="users-number"></p>
      <span id="price5">14</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</button>


<button class="desactivate" type="button" id="btn-book-12">
  <div>
    <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
      <p>Items 6</p>
      <br>
      <p id="users-number"></p>
      <span id="price6">16</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</button>

<button class="active" type="button" id="btn-book-13">
  <div>
    <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
      <p>Items 7</p>
      <br>
      <p id="users-number"></p>
      <span id="price7">12</span>
    </span>
  </div>
</button>


<span id="amountInDollars"></span>
```

Comment: Well, that wasn't required in the OP question so I've assumed that elements will always have price, but I'll correct the code to support your note i.e. instead of `parseInt` I'll put `Number` as `Number('')` will return `0` and `.text()` is returning a string. That's first. And second, I'll check for an empty array.

Comment: You are welcome, you can delete the comments

Comment: No need of deleting, you've made a good note.

Answer (score 0):

Firstable I see no purpose for adding class name `desactivate` cause each non active button is desactive by natural, the price span element should have a class name `price` only instead of ids, and you can use event delegation to do these type of things, and you could use divs instead of buttons, but I didn't modify the rest of your HTML it's up to you.

**Edited:** added button click canceling feature

```js
let total = 0;
document.querySelector("#buttons").onclick = function(e) {
  // because you have elements inside of your button! so we count all the clicks on the button no matter what element is targeted
  let targetButton = e.target.closest("button");
  if(targetButton) {
    let price = targetButton.querySelector(".price").textContent;
    // if the button is active then desactivate it and subtract the price from the total, else set the button as active and add the price to the total
    if(targetButton.className.includes("active")) {
      // set the button to inactive state
      targetButton.classList.remove("active");
      total -= price;
    }else {
      // set the button to active state
      targetButton.classList.add("active");
      total += Number(price);
    }
    // update the total amount element's content
    document.querySelector("#amountInDollars").textContent = total;
  }
};
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
 <button type="button" id="btn1">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 1</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span class="price">10</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>
<button type="button" id="btn20">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 2</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span class="price">20</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>
<button type="button" id="btn6">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 3</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span class="price">19</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-book-6">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 4</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span class="price">13</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>

<button type="button" id="btn-book-20">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 5</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span class="price">14</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>


<button type="button" id="btn-book-12">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 6</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span class="price">16</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>

<button type="button" id="btn-book-13">
    <div>
        <span class="lg:text-base text-xs">
            <p>Items 7</p>
            <br>
            <p id="users-number"></p>
            <span class="price">12</span>
        </span>
    </div>
</button>
</div>

<br>
<span id="amountInDollars">0</span>
```